# Tec Tac Toc doesn't update the moves on the board

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to make "Tec Tac Toc" game  from a book I have.

The problem is that I get no player moves update on the board. I only get the computer move.

What should I do to fix the problem?

I tried to make the code as clear as possible.

The code I wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TecTacToe {


  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);  





  private char[][] squares ;
```

ddd

```
  public  TecTacToe() {



 squares=new char[][]{{'.' , '.', '.'},
                      {'.' , '.', '.'}  ,      
                      {'.' , '.', '.'}};



  }
```

dd

```
  public String toString(){
  String result="";
   for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
           for(int column=0;column<3;column++){
               result+=squares[row][column];



           }
           result+="\n";
      }
  return result;

  }
```

fff

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {


        TecTacToe game= new TecTacToe();
         System.out.println("welcome to Tic Tac Toe");
         game.play();
          System.out.println(game);
           System.out.println("Game over");





}
```

dd

```
public boolean gameOver(){
  if(score()!=0){
  return true;

  }

   for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
      for(int column=0;column<3;column++){

         if(squares[row][column]=='.'){

          return false;
         } //end of if statment
      }//second loop
   }// first loop
   return true;
      }// end of game over class
```

ff

```
public int score(){

  int lineScore;

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

  lineScore=scoreLine(squares[i][0],squares[i][1],squares[i][2]);

  if(lineScore!=0){
      return lineScore;
  }

  lineScore=scoreLine(squares[0][i],squares[1][i],squares[2][i]);

   if(lineScore!=0){
      return lineScore;
  }
     }

    lineScore=scoreLine(squares[0][0],squares[1][1],squares[2][2]);

   if(lineScore!=0){
      return lineScore;
  }


   return scoreLine(squares[0][2],squares[1][1],squares[2][0]);



  }
```

ddd

```
 protected int scoreLine(char a,char b, char c){

  if( (a=='X') && (b=='X')&& (c=='X')){ return 1;}

    if((a=='O')&&(b=='O')&&(c=='O')) {return -1;}

  return 0;
  }
```

ddd

```
  public void play(){

char player ='X';
for(int move=0;move<9;move++){
if(gameOver()){
return;

}
if(player=='X'){
playbestMove();
player='0';
}
else{
    System.out.println(this);
    System.out.println("Enter the row: ");
 int row=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the column: ");
 int column=input.nextInt();      

    squares[row][column]='0';
    player='X';
}


}


}
```

ddd

```
 protected void playbestMove(){

  int score;
  int bestScore=-2;
  int bestRow=-1;
  int bestColumn=-1;

  for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
  for(int column=0;column<3;column++){
     if(squares[row][column]=='.'){
     squares[row][column]='X';
     score=score();
     bestRow=row;
     bestColumn=column;
     }
     squares[row][column]='.';
  }
  }


  squares[bestRow][bestColumn]='X';
  }
```

ddd

```
  }//end of tec tac toe class
```

Comment: Is there a deeper sense in those "ddd"s and "fff"s?

Comment: @CurlyB: I've used periods to separate code blocks, although not as many as freedom12.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in your code.

- in `playBestMove()` , `squares[row][column] = '.'` should go inside the if statement, otherwise it deletes all previous moves.
- In `play()` you use the character `0` (zero) for the human player, but in scoreline you check for `O` (the vowel)

Also, your `playBestMove` algorithm just puts the cross on the last available position, not really the best move.